# dynamic textboxes not working in updatepanel

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-ajax

I am creating dynamic text boxes on button click and then showing values on another button click. It works fine until I use ajax updatepanel. In that case values are not shown when I hit second button. My aspx code is:

aspx markup is:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div id="divRT" runat="server">
        </div>
           <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnAccessValues" EventName="Click" />
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="lbnAddNew" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<div>
    <asp:Button ID="btnAccessValues" Text="save" runat="Server" OnClick="btnAccessValues_Click" />
    <br />
    <br />       
</div>
```

Code to show values.

```
 Protected Sub btnAccessValues_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnAccessValues.Click
        If ViewState(strVS_DynamicIds) IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim lstDynId As List(Of String) = DirectCast(ViewState(strVS_DynamicIds), List(Of String))
            For Each strId As String In lstDynId
                Dim tbx As TextBox = DirectCast(divRT.FindControl(strId), TextBox)

                Response.Write(tbx.Text)
                Label1.Text = tbx.Text
            Next
        End If
    End Sub
```

I am using this article as reference:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/abhijeetsinghai/creating-textboxes-dynamically-at-runtime/

Please suggest solution.

Regards,
Asif Hameed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When i try implementing your scenario the only problem i found is the triggers, So comment triggers in your code and then try it again

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div id="divRT" runat="server">
        </div>
           <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    </ContentTemplate>        
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<div>
    <asp:Button ID="btnAccessValues" Text="save" runat="Server" OnClick="btnAccessValues_Click" />
    <br />
    <br />       
</div>
```

Comment: Hi I removed the triggeres but same error. Values in textboxes are not accessible after postback

Comment: Show me your complete code. I have already implement that blog code and working fine with update panel

Answer (score 0):

you must had to recreate your dynamically added controls on each post back..
so either recreate them in Page_Init Or Page_Load.

Comment: I am creating these textboxes on listbox selected index change. I pass selectedindex as parameter to function which then calls a db stored procedure. If I try to call this method in page_init , selected index is always blank/

Comment: I meant to say that you must had to redefine them before you access them..in your case i think you can take help of ViewState in page load to redefine your texboxes..??? got my point ? i.e store your selectedindex in ViewState and use it on Page_Load..